# Using AngularJS with Crossrider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, crossrider

I have started testing Crossrider to build browser extensions and I think is has some potential.

I would like to use AngularJS alongside with crossrider. Is that possible?

Comment: Whilst I haven't used it myself, I know that AngularJS has been successfully used in building several extensions using the Crossrider framework. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Okay. I want to see some examples... Can you help me with that?

Comment: As mentioned, it's not something that I've used myself and I can't provide code from other developers extensions. I suggest you try it yourself, and if you have any issues/questions please feel free to ask and I will try to help.

Comment: Appreciate your support... by the time you were writing this answer I've done some tests with Crossrider framework and AngularJS. Although, if any issues/questions comes up I will certainly will try to get help.

Comment: One quick question: there's any compatible issue implementing AngularJS with Crossrider framework?

Comment: I am not aware of any compatibility issues with implementing AngularJS with Crossrider framework.

Comment: Can you point me to an example to one of the extensions built with AngularJS?

Comment: Currently, there isn't a demo extension available to demonstrate how to use AngularJS. As mentioned previously, feel free to try it yourself, and if you have any issues/questions please feel free to ask and I will try to help. If you prefer to keep this private, please email support@crossrider.com where we will be happy to assist.